# Сохранения данных в базу

Tags: ооп, c++

Вообщем вопрос состоит в следующем.
Пользователь вводит с клавиатуры информацию. Которая должна записаться в файл (самописная бд). Корректно ли будет если значения полей бд приставить в виде структуры, которую сделать за классом не в средине, т.к метод ввода с клавиатуры сохраняет значения в нужные переменные структуры и возвращает ее. После чего она через fopen открытым банарно записывается в файл.
Или же все таки структуру заменить классом?

Comment: >Корректно ли будет если значения полей бд приставить в виде структуры, которую сделать за классом не в средине, т.к метод ввода с клавиатуры сохраняет значения в нужные переменные структуры и возвращает ее

что за бред?

Comment: struct DB_struct {

}

class MyClass
{
...........
DB_struct input() {
....
}
}

Comment: @miyu вы пожалуйста грамотным русским языком опишите, что именно вам нужно. То, что у вас сейчас написано в вопросе, больше походит на наркотический бред, нежели на вопрос, уж извините